# Store data not set after load grid ui

Tags: magento2, stores, uicomponent

I have created my own custom module. Entity like Block and Page of module cms. Everything ok. My form can save data to db. In my form i have field to set which store to belong. It like cms blog store implement. But after load, store data seem not set in grid
Why it happen? In grid ui column store empty. Grid JSON show store_id empty And in form store data not set. But data in db existed. What did i do wrong? How to make form set data for select store field

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found my problems

Some parts in my etc/`di.xml` file

```
<type name="{{Namespace}}\{{Module}}\Model\ResourceModel\{{Entity}}\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">{{your-entity-table}}</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">{{youreventprefix}}</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">{{youreventobject}}</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">{{Namespace}}\{{Module}}\Model\ResourceModel\{{Entity}}</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="your_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">{{Namespace}}\{{Module}}\Model\ResourceModel\{{Entity}}\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

No need this below

```
<virtualType name="{{Namespace}}\{{Module}}\Model\ResourceModel\{{Entity}}\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">{{your-entity-table}}</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">{{youreventprefix}}</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">{{youreventobject}}</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">{{Namespace}}\{{Module}}\Model\ResourceModel\{{Entity}}</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

New GridUI comes with some implement interface you can see in `module-cms`
Don't forget Grid Collection located in

{{Namespace}}\{{Module}}\Model\ResourceModel\{{Entity}}\Grid\Collection. This implement SearchResultInterface for get collection data of entity and populate all to your grid